# Should I recall when my carry does or not?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm often playing *support* in match games, and so I generally pick a *carry* to follow, but don't have a lot of active coordination from them.  One situation that comes up multiple times a game is that my *carry* recalls leaving me alone in the lane.  Should I time my recalls for when my *carry* recalls or when my *carry* is on deck?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is one definitive answer possible, it really depends on the situation, but as a **very general** rule of thumb you could say that you should base together with your carry if the lane is pushed so that no xp will be lost in the time the two of you are gone. If minions are going to be near your tower soon when your carry goes base, you should stay and freeze the lane, if minions are far enough out you can safely base together.

Keep in mind that this is very broad. There are a lot of factors that are of influence and most of the time you should consider the situation and decide on the spot whether to base or not.

One thing that is certain is that if you decide to stay in lane, you should not push. Just last hit minions if they otherwise reach your tower, but try to take as little xp and gold while your carry is gone.

Comment: I'll just add that if you don't need to recall (you're not low on health, mana, or under significant threat of a tower dive gank through your jungle, and you don't have gold saved up to buy a core/rush item), then don't. This is especially true before you hit level 6, as by staying in lane by yourself, you'll gain XP faster (stay within XP range of the minion wave if you can). If your carry has been forced back and the enemy duo is still in lane, you might be able to hit 6 early so that just as the carry returns, you can try and make a sneaky surprise play.

Answer (score 2):

If your carry goes back you need to hold the lane if possible (e.g. if it's unlikely that you get killed), in order to avoid the tower getting damage. If your lane is already pushed or there is a teamfight nearby it is also good to help other lanes.

Sometimes it is even wise to push the lane and the tower while the carry is away, however, only if there is no danger. That's more gold & exp for you and and a earlier tower kill for your team. And towers are very important for your team.

Note that in Season 3 the support could not carry, and thus every advantage should've been given to the ADC, this is **not** the case anymore in Season 4 due to assist sprees and better gold items.

You **can** carry, if your selfishness helps your team in the late game, do it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok im no xpecial or anything, and yes I am in bronze, but I watch streams and tournaments, and tend to main support, if you look me up (tataku999) most of my ranked games are support.

Now here is my rule or where im at with this, because its something that I think about all the time.

here a a few good scenarios to consider. the first one: lets say your lane is pushed and your carry dies. If you teleport, your turret is most likely going to fall, so you might want to hold. Also in the these situations is always a good idea to ping for help, whether or not he comes is fine, but now you have his attention so if he is a good jungle he will reconsider his routes. DO NOT BUG HIM. if you do this he will rage and you might lose. Just have it more as a gentle reminder.

Second: Make sure the lane is somewhat pushed before anyone goes back. Again if its pushed your turret can fall. If you need to heal use whatever mana you have because you should be goign back anyways.

So for this if you have gold to get an item you need, especially a sight stone, go back with them. this way you are sure to not get caught by yourself or something stupid.

The other situation is if you have a few wards and no one is around, go throw some wards down the go b.

Similarly if there is no wards down and you are pushed (which imo you shouldnt), I would find a safe time, and go back a get wards as fast as you can while your carry can farm.

So my answer is yes, but there are some cases when you should stay.

Edit: I dont like to push the lane, but if the adc is gone and you are under tower, not not a bad idea to last hit a few creeps. better you then the tower getting all that gold.